# How do you provide intellisense for a specific file through a vscode extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to provide intellisense for when a user types an object in their code, i.e. like so:

```
const obj = { };
```

In Typescript, a user would be able to type their object, like so:

```
const obj: objConfig = { };
```

Unfortunately, I'd also like to provide intellisense for users who don't use Typescript. I have no idea how to use an example.d.ts file in my extension to provide intellisense for the user.

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: if you are talking about js files, typescript also understands jsdoc comments which can be used as basically type annotations

Comment: and you can set `allowJS` to `true` in `tsconfig.json` or in preferences, and then JS will also get type checked.